# pandas rolling sum return time series

Tags: python, pandas

data

```
data = [
    {"content": "1", "title": "app sotre", "info": "", "time": 1578877014},
    {"content": "2", "title": "app", "info": "", "time": 1579877014},
    {"content": "3", "title": "pandas", "info": "", "time": 1582877014},
    {"content": "12", "title": "a", "info": "", "time": 1582876014},
    {"content": "33", "title": "apple", "info": "", "time": 1581877014},
    {"content": "16", "title": "banana", "info": "", "time": 1561877014},
    {"content": "aa", "title": "banana", "info": "", "time": 1582876014},
]
```

my code

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df['content'] = pd.to_numeric(df['content'], errors='coerce')
df['content'].rolling(3).sum()

0     NaN
1     NaN
2     6.0
3    17.0
4    48.0
5    61.0
```

i first time use dataframe,So I ’m not familiar with how the dataframe  replace the content data
i hope data

```
[
    {"content": "NaN", "title": "app sotre", "info": "", "time": 1578877014},
    {"content": "NaN", "title": "app", "info": "", "time": 1579877014},
    {"content": "6", "title": "pandas", "info": "", "time": 1582877014},
    {"content": "17", "title": "a", "info": "", "time": 1582876014},
    {"content": "48", "title": "apple", "info": "", "time": 1581877014},
    {"content": "61.0", "title": "banana", "info": "", "time": 1561877014},
    {"content": "NaN", "title": "banana", "info": "", "time": 1582876014},
]
```

Comment: `df['content'] = df['content'].rolling(3).sum()` ?

Comment: What is the question here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply assign to column

```
 df['content'] = df['content'].rolling(3).sum()
```

---

```
import pandas as pd

data = [
    {"content": "1", "title": "app sotre", "info": "", "time": 1578877014},
    {"content": "2", "title": "app", "info": "", "time": 1579877014},
    {"content": "3", "title": "pandas", "info": "", "time": 1582877014},
    {"content": "12", "title": "a", "info": "", "time": 1582876014},
    {"content": "33", "title": "apple", "info": "", "time": 1581877014},
    {"content": "16", "title": "banana", "info": "", "time": 1561877014},
    {"content": "aa", "title": "banana", "info": "", "time": 1582876014},
]

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df['content'] = pd.to_numeric(df['content'], errors='coerce')
df['content'] = df['content'].rolling(3).sum()

print( df )

#df['content'] = df['content'].astype(str)
#print( df.to_dict('record') )
```

Result

```
   content      title info        time
0      NaN  app sotre       1578877014
1      NaN        app       1579877014
2      6.0     pandas       1582877014
3     17.0          a       1582876014
4     48.0      apple       1581877014
5     61.0     banana       1561877014
6      NaN     banana       1582876014
```